# Python simplify list items

Tags: python, list, python-3.5, discord.py

I am using an API wrapper for AniList called PyMoe. And using this for my Discord Bot.
Here is the code I am using:

```
>>> import Pymoe
>>> An = Pymoe.Anilist()
>>> search = An.search.anime('SNK')
>>> ide = search['data']['Page']['media'][0]['id']
>>> id = An.get.anime(ide)
>>> genres = id['data']['Media']['genres']
>>> genres
['Action', 'Drama', 'Fantasy']
```

When i use the code for my Discord bot I am getting that [result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YpPsi.png). But I don't want these `[']` stuffs. I want this like `Genre 1, Genre 2, Genre 3`. I researched a little bit about this but i didn't find anything. So if it is possible (or not) let me know.

Comment: Don't rely on the string representation of the list? format it yourself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `join()` method to solve the issue

```
genres = id['data']['Media']['genres']
genres = ', '.join(genres)
```

This should give you the output

> Action, Drama, Fantasy

Comment: I am looking the code for my Discord bot, not for terminal. I mean not with the print command. It works at terminal but not at Discord.

Comment: use `join()` and save it into a variable, after that you can use the variable for your bot